# Filling in gaps in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Having a tough time with multi dimensional arrays. 
I have a table of films and a table of ratings for these films.

I want to be able to create an array for each user based on their ratings, for example user1 would look like `Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [34] => 5 ) )`. So within the second array, the indexes are the filmID and their values are the film ratings.

I have succeeded in doing this, however I then need to see if a user has not rated a film, and if this is the case, an index needs to be created for this film in the array, with the value of 0. This is so all user rating arrays are the same length, and can then be run through a function to compare how similar their ratings are.

```
$similarArray = array();

$films = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM films");
$users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");

while ($userRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    $similarCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE userID = ".$userRow['userID']);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($similarCheck)) {
            $similarArray[$userRow['userID']][$row['Film_ID']] = $row['rating'];
    }
}

echo'<pre>'.print_r($similarArray).'</pre>';
```

That is how I am creating the multi dimensional arrays, just unsure as to how to 'fill in the gaps'.

Thanks for any help I receive, and if you're confused or need any more information, just let me know.

**EDIT**
I have just written the following code:

```
while ($userRow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($user2)){
    while ($filmRow2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($films2)){
        if (array_key_exists ($filmRow2['Film_ID'], $similarArray[$userRow2['userID']])) {
            echo "exists";
        } else {
            $similarArray[$userRow2['userID']][$filmRow2['Film_ID']] = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

This works for ONE user in the database, creating n number of array keys with a rating of 0 based on how many films are in the database, however it stops once it gets to the next user.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assume that if it doesn't exist, it's 0?

```
if(empty($userRow['userID']][$row['Film_ID'])){
    //user hasn't rated it
}else{
    //user did rate it
}
```